# PHP Curl shows different page than in the browser

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to scrape a list of bills from a website after logging into it via curl but on one of the pages the content is not the same as in my browser (namely, instead of showing a list of bills it shows "Your bill history cannot be displayed"). I can correctly scrape other pages that are only available after login so I'm quite puzzled by why that page refuse to display the bill history when I use curl.

Here is my code:

```
//Load login page
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.domain.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.domain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieLocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieLocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$webpage = curl_exec($ch);

//Submit post to login page to authentify
$postVariables = 'emailAddress='.$username.
    '&password='.$password;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVariables);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.domain.com/login/POST.servlet');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.domain.com/login');
$webpage = curl_exec($ch);

//Go to my account main page now that we are logged in
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.domain.com/My_Account');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $target);
$webpage = curl_exec($ch); //shows the same content as in the browser
$accountNumber = return_between($webpage, 'id="accountID1">', '<', EXCL); //this is correctly found

//Go to bills page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.domain.com/Bill_History/?accountnumber='.$accountNumber);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.domain.com/My_Account');
$webpage = curl_exec($ch); //Not showing the same content as in the browser
```

The last curl_exec being the one that doesn't work properly.

I have checked extensively the logic of the page and used Tamper Data to analyse what was going on: there doesn't seem to be any javascript / ajax call that would pull the bill history separately, and no POST request: as far as I can see the bill history should be displayed at page load.

Any ideas as to what I could try to fix it or what could be the problem? The fact that it works on other pages is especially puzzling.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: it still doesn't work but I have found another page on their site where I can get what I need and where the content is displayed correctly - so no need for a solution anymore.

Comment: They may have htaccess rules that prevent scripting...

Comment: How could I bypass these rules? I assume it is possible to make the believe I am a browser visitor.

Comment: If they had something preventing crawling, scraping, or whatever, faking user agent may get you around it. (this is all an assumption, I dont know what they have set up, or who they are)

Comment: I've worked on sites that require human interaction by computing cycles of interactions, like I said, no idea what they have set up, those are just potentials.

Comment: What do you mean by circles of interactions?

Comment: Are your `$username` and `$password` [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)d?

Comment: Also, use a packet analyzer to figure out what data you're actually sending. Ensure that your "Content-Type" is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or whatever value is normally being used when you sign in manually.

Comment: Something like `drag and drop` interactions uses more CYCLES by a human that if it were automated.

Comment: @Spooky yes they are - the logging in part works fine

Answer (score 0):

You might add additional header fields that "real" browsers usually transmit:

```
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
```

Just to name a few.

If you happen to use FFox, get that handy "Live HTTP Headers" plugin and check what headers your browser transmits when loading the relevant page. Then try to do the same.

Comment: Thanks - I've added that (based on Tamper Data header request shown) and it still displays the same error message.